# How to update a div's style in an Angular component

Tags: angular

I want to set the style of an element in a dropdown list component. Should I just set it using ngStyle?

**Here is template/HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown-items" *ngIf="showList" [style]="top: elHeight">
   <li *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems">
      {{item.name}}
   </li>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to add style dynamically i.e is it conditional?

Comment: yes im just going to use [style.height.px]="..." i can't delete the question

Comment: cool that would be the way to go about it

Answer (score 0):

use li{} in CSS to style all the dropdown list elements or if you want to style a specific element give ids to ngFor elements using [id]=index and then style the element using #id in CSS

Answer (score 0):

write two CSS classes and update class name based on conditions.
ex:

```
// mprn-status-count.component.html

    <div class="dropdown-items" *ngIf="showList" [ngClass]="(iscssupdate==true)?'updatedclass':'priviousclass'">
       <li *ngFor="let item of dropdownItems">
          {{item.name}}
       </li>   

       </div>

    //component.css
    .updatedclass{
    // update css 
    }        
    .priviousclass{
    // privious css 
    }
```

Comment: the height is not static though

Comment: .updatedclass{
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}     use css calc fucntion.